# Get specific fields from index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elastic-search.

Sample structure :

```
{
    "Article": "Article7645674712",
    "Genre": "Genre92231455",
    "relationDesc": [
        "Article",
        "Genre"
    ],
    "org": "user",
    "dateCreated": {
        "date": "08/05/2015",
        "time": "16:22 IST"
    },
    "dateModified": "08/05/2015"
}
```

From this index i want to retrieve selected fields: **org** and **dateModified**.

I want result like this

```
{
    "took": 265,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 28,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "couchrecords",
                "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "doc": {
                        "org": "user",
                        "dateModified": "08/05/2015"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "couchrecords",
                "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "doc": {
                        "org": "user",
                        "dateModified": "10/05/2015"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to query elastic-search to get only selected specific fields ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve only a specific set of fields in the result hits using the [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_4) parameter like this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/couchrecords/couchbaseDocument/_search?_source=org,dateModified
```

Or in this format:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/couchrecords/couchbaseDocument/_search -d '{
    "_source": ["doc.org", "doc.dateModified"],  <---- you just need to add this
    "query": {
        "match_all":{}   <----- or whatever query you have
    }
}'
```

Comment: I write query like {"query":{
"_source":["org"]
}} but it is giving error

Comment: It is  giving output like {
    "_index": "couchrecords",
    "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": { }

}

Comment: Something's wrong with how your documents were indexed. What do you see when running this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/couchrecords/couchbaseDocument/3`? Also can you update your question with the `couchbaseDocument ` mapping you're using, i.e. do you have `"_source" : {"enabled" : false}` somewhere in them?

Comment: no  I am not using "_source" : {"enabled" : false} my mapping is normal

Comment: What does this return `curl -XGET localhost:9200/couchrecords/couchbaseDocument/3` ?

Comment: {
    "_index": "couchrecords",
    "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
    "_id": "3",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "doc": {
            "Article": "Article764567",
            "Genre": "Genre922332",
            "relationDesc": [
                "Article", "Genre"],
            "org": "user",
            "recordId": "ArticleGenre5eb3a",
            "author": "User3641dc",
            "editor": "User3641dc",
            "dateCreated": {
                "date": "08/05/2015",          "time": "16:22 IST"      }, "dateModified": "08/05      /2015","revison": "1"}}}

Comment: Oh I see all your properties are nested inside a `doc` field actually. I've updated my answer, you can use this instead: `"_source": ["doc.org", "doc.dateModified"]`

Comment: But from doc i want org and dateModified fields,not required total doc

Comment: thank you for spending time to give solution to my question.Now it is working

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. Considering any query of this format :

```
{
  "query": {
  ...
  },
}
```

You'll just need to add the `fields` field into your query which in your case will result in the following :

```
{
  "query": {
  ...
  },
  "fields" : ["org","dateModified"]
}
```

Comment: I write  {"query":{
"match_all":{}}, "fields" : ["org","dateModified"]}   and i get result as {
    "took": 32,"timed_out": false,"_shards": {
        "total": 5,"successful": 5,
        "failed": 0},"hits": {"total": 28, "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            { "_index": "couchrecords",
                "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1
            }
            ,
            {
                "_index": "couchrecords",
                "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
                "_id": "8",
                "_score": 1
            }

Comment: update with your question with your query. something might be wrong with it!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "_source" : ["org","dateModified"],
  "query": {
  ...
  }
}
```

Check ElasticSearch [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering).